# Utilizando TLS 1.2 no .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, segurança, webclient, tls

Estou querendo utilizar TLS 1.2 numa chamada `Webclient` no *framework* .NET 2.0

É possível?

```
try
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        string u = client.UploadString(url, xml);
        return u;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível, pelo menos de forma direta, só no 4.5 para cima. O .NET 2.0 não é mais suportado há bastante tempo e não deveria estar sendo usado, ele não recebe atualizações de segurança.

Quem sabe consiga pegar [o fonte](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs) e adaptar para se uso (mas não é algo trivial).

Aproveita e melhore o código:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    return client.UploadString(url, xml);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ReturnOnUsing.cs).

Bem mais simples, né? A captura da exceção só está causando problemas para o código. Só capture exceção para fazer algo útil. O que está fazendo é só estragar o *stack trace*.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dizer como é possível fazer isto no .NET 2.0